# GIMP Text along creates jaggies

Tags: gimp, text

I have just learned (thanks to tutorial at http://buttner-jenkins.blogspot.com/2010/04/gimp-tut-text-along-path.html) how to create a text along path.

When I followed these instructions, though, using Nimbus Roman No9 Latin, to render my text in an arc, the text ended up with jaggies at all of the edges. I'm wondering if there's some kind of automated way to smooth away these jaggies.

Thanks.

Comment: It would greatly help us if you could post a screenshot of the problem and maybe also the resulting image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a screenshot or the GIMP file, I'm guessing that perhaps somewhere along the line you did a selection or flood fill that wasn't properly anti-aliased.  Did you use a select tool to move text at any stage and perhaps change the background behind it or something?

Perhaps you could repeat the instructions again keeping the text on its own layer which you don't do anything else to.